# Engage "Lumo compact mode" in Vaadin 13 and later, for smaller size layouts

Tags: java, css, layout, vaadin, vaadin-flow

The release notes for Vaadin 13 includes an item for [*Lumo compact mode*](https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-13#compact-theme). The mention there is brief, lacking details. To quote:

> The compact theme/preset defines values for the sizing and spacing properties to reduce the visual space required by components to better fit a large amount of content on the screen. It’s a Lumo-only feature and can be enabled by importing the preset file to the application.

How do I turn on this compact mode in my Vaadin 14 web app?

Comment: For a similar Question on the predecessor to *Lumo* theme, the *Valo* theme, see: [*Scale down the Valo theme’s spacing and widget size to that of the Reindeer theme*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26579458/642706).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Add two annotations: `@JsModule` & `@Theme`

I found a bit more documentation on this tutorial, [*Themes and styling in Vaadin*](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/themes-and-styling-in-vaadin), by Jouni Koivuviita on the Vaadin.com site. See [Use global variants > Compact](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/themes-and-styling-in-vaadin#_compact).

Add three imports:

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.lumo.Lumo;
```

Add two annotations:

```
@JsModule ("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/presets/compact.js")
@Theme ( Lumo.class)
```

To quote the tutorial:

> Technically, it adds a `<style>` element to the page which sets new values for the [Lumo sizing and spacing CSS properties](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-lumo-styles/1.5.0/demo/sizing-and-spacing.html). You can [view the values from the source code](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/blob/master/presets/compact.html).

For more technical detail, including a list of affected CSS properties, see that first link in tutorial: [*Compact preset*](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-lumo-styles/1.5.0/demo/sizing-and-spacing.html#compact-preset) in the *Lumo* styles demo site. And see the actual code in that second link, the GitHub page: [*vaadin-lumo-styles/presets/compact.html*](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/blob/master/presets/compact.html).

Put that together into a demo class. We are modifying the `MainView` class generated in a new project by the Vaadin.com [project starters page](https://vaadin.com/start/latest), for Vaadin 14.1.17.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Key;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.select.Select;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.lumo.Lumo;


/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@JsModule ( "@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/presets/compact.js" )
@Theme ( Lumo.class )
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
@CssImport ( "./styles/shared-styles.css" )
@CssImport ( value = "./styles/vaadin-text-field-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{
    enum Animal { DOG, CAT, BIRD, HAMSTER } ;

    public MainView ( )
    {
        // Use TextField for standard text input
        TextField textField = new TextField( "Your name" );

        // Button click listeners can be defined as lambda expressions
        GreetService greetService = new GreetService();
        Button button = new Button( "Say hello" ,
                e -> Notification.show( greetService.greet( textField.getValue() ) ) );

        // Theme variants give you predefined extra styles for components.
        // Example: Primary button is more prominent look.
        button.addThemeVariants( ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY );

        // You can specify keyboard shortcuts for buttons.
        // Example: Pressing enter in this view clicks the Button.
        button.addClickShortcut( Key.ENTER );

        // Use custom CSS classes to apply styling. This is defined in shared-styles.css.
        this.addClassName( "centered-content" );


        Select < Animal > animalSelect = new Select <>();
        animalSelect.setItems( Animal.values() );
        this.add( animalSelect , new TextField( "Bogus1" ) , new TextField( "Bogus2" ) , new TextField( "Bogus3" ) , new TextField( "Bogus4" ) , textField , button );
    }
}
```

Here is the result when running with the embedded Jetty server to Microsoft Edge v 80.0.361.57 client on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

[image: Screenshot of the above code showing two browser windows, each rendered with and without the two annotations discussed above showing the resulting decrease of both the widgets and their spacing.]

I am not clear on whether you need to annotate every one of your UI classes or just the `MainView.java`. I would guess you must annotate every UI class.

Comment: Annotating `MainView` should be enough, assuming `MainView` is the parent of all your views.